# Django/Bootstrap Modal not submitting

Tags: python, ajax, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to submit Django forms in Bootstrap 4 modals with AJAX, but it doesnt submit for some reason. When you click on the submit button it just closes the modal and nothing else happens. The content shows correctly in the modal body at least, but it just doesnt submit.

Here is my view

```
class GaasWaferDesignFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, AjaxTemplateMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'engineering/gaas_wafer_designs/gaas_wafer_design_form.html'
    ajax_template_name = 'engineering/gaas_wafer_designs/gaas_wafer_design_form_inner.html'
    form_class = GaasWaferDesignForm
    model = GaasWaferDesign
    form = GaasWaferDesignForm()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('engineering:gaas_wafer_design_list')
    success_message = "Success!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.created_by = self.request.user
        object.save()
        return super(GaasWaferDesignCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And here is my template which has the modal structure and button for the modal(gaas_wafer_design_list.html)...

```
{% extends "pages/list_template.html" %}{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}GaAs Wafer Design List{% endblock %}
{% block list_title %}GaAs Wafer Designs{% endblock %}
{% block list_title_2 %}Design Inventory{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js%}

{% endblock %}

{% block buttons %}
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" style="margin-bottom: -150px; z-index:1000;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form-modal" id="create-button">Create a new wafer design</button>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a id="btnGroupDrop1" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          View
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Recycling Bin</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block table %}
<div class="modal fade" id="form-modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Wafer Design</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
              <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div id="form-modal-body" class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Wafer Design UI
          </th>
          <th>
              Emitting Type
          </th>
          <th>
              Contact Location
          </th>
          <th>
              Optical Power
          </th>
          <th>
              Design Date
          </th>
          <th>
              Designer
          </th>
          <th>
              Designer UI
          </th>
          <th>
              Created At
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>
              Wafer Design UI
          </th>
          <th>
              Emitting Type
          </th>
          <th>
              Contact Location
          </th>
          <th>
              Optical Power
          </th>
          <th>
              Design Date
          </th>
          <th>
              Designer
          </th>
          <th>
              Designer UI
          </th>
          <th>
              Created At
          </th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
      {% for gaas_wafer_design in gaas_wafer_designs %}
      <tr>
          <td><a href="{% url 'engineering:gaas_wafer_design_detail' pk=gaas_wafer_design.pk %}">{{ gaas_wafer_design.design_ui }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.get_emitting_display }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.contact_location }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.optical_power }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.design_date|date:"m/d/y" }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.designer }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.designer_ui }}</td>
          <td>{{ gaas_wafer_design.created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</tbody>

<script>
var formAjaxSubmit = function(form, modal) {
    $(form).submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if ( $(xhr).find('.has-error').length > 0 ) {
                   $(modal).find('.modal-body').html(xhr);
                   formAjaxSubmit(form, modal);
               } else {
                   $(modal).modal('toggle');
               }
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               // handle response errors here
           }
       });
   });
}
$('#create-button').click(function() {
   $('#form-modal-body').load('create/', function () {
       $('#form-modal').modal('toggle');
       formAjaxSubmit('#form-modal-body form', '#form-modal');
   });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my url...

```
url(r'^gaas-wafer-designs/create/$', gaas_wafer_designs.GaasWaferDesignFormView.as_view(), name='gaas_wafer_design_create'),
```

And lastly here is my gaas_wafer_design_form_inner.html (template which has the modal body content)

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'engineering:gaas_wafer_design_create' %}">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.design_ui.id_for_label }}"><b>Design UI</b></label>
        {% render_field form.design_ui class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.design_ui.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.emitting.id_for_label }}"><b>Emitting</b></label>
        {% render_field form.emitting class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.emitting.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.contact_location.id_for_label }}"><b>Contact Location</b></label>
        {% render_field form.contact_location class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.contact_location.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.optical_power.id_for_label }}">Optical Power</label>
        {% render_field form.optical_power class+="form-control" %}
        {{ form.optical_power.errors }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
</form>
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the object is created, but your form_valid doesn't return to the success_url. At the end of your form_valid you should redirect to success_url. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with your return at the end of form_valid.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And you can than also override success_url and add massage if needed.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    # add message
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your message.')

    # reverse back to providers' page with success message
    return reverse_lazy('engineering:gaas_wafer_design_list')
```

I have written a simple to use package for such functionalities and you can check it out at [django-bootstrap-modal-forms](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms).

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the package!

Comment: I tried installing your modal package and following instructions but unfortunately it isnt working for me. I click the button and no modal comes up, nothing in the javascript console either. It looked like a nice solution with elegant code, not sure why its not working

Comment: @user3005684 Please double check that you did setup everything as in my example. I rechecked the example and it works as intended. If your trigger element is not opening modal, first check that the ''id'' of the trigger element matches the one you select with jquery selector in script. In my example the ''id'' of the trigger element for modal opening is createTest and jquery selector for this element that the modalForm is bound to is $(''#createTest'').

Comment: I posted an answer below since I needed to include code and images